# differentiate between Four-finger swipe and home key press event

Tags: ios, ipad, background-process, uiswipegesturerecognizer

Currently in my iOS app, i'm able to capture the home key pressed event by **UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification**.

But the **Four-finger swipe gesture of iPad** also generates the same event as the functionality is same for both the events..

I need to differentiate between these two events..

Any help would be appreciated..    thanks..

Comment: You could create a gesture recognizer for the four finger swipe and see if you can capture that?

Comment: @stevekohls :  I have tried that. I don't think this will suffice my requirement. What I need to know is, which event ( Four-finger swipe gesture OR Home button ) has caused my app to go into background. If I create a gesture recognizer for the four finger swipe, it will recognize even if I only touch four fingers on the screen.